# Why don't we have string constants for some Encoding name and code pages in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, constants

From [MSDN documentation for EncodingInfo.GetEncoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encodinginfo.getencoding?view=net-5.0):

For instance, if I need to use  `iso-8859-1, Western European (ISO), codepage = 28591`, I will call `Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")`

I'm wondering is there some sort of predefined string constant or Enum in .NET for these encoding names?

And if there isn't, why is it designed that way?

Is the name of the encoding expected to change in the future or something?

Comment: a) probably not, b) that's what they chose, c) no idea go ask them

Comment: regarding the future then we will se a consolidation towards utf-8 and the other standards that are generally supported. But that was also what I would have said 20 years ago and at least in some sectors reality moves very slow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any built-in Encoding Enum in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40658616/is-there-any-built-in-encoding-enum-in-c)

Comment: @imsmn: thanks, but I would love to hear the design rationale rather than knowing whether there exists such a thing or not.

Comment: Maybe [Encoding.GetEncodings Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getencodings?view=net-5.0)?